# "dynamical storage" with memcpy

Tags: c++, data-structures, memcpy

I'm working with a library that uses "memcpy" to simulate dynamical storage data structure with direct access. It's important to note that I'm working on numerical operations that result with small data sets. How can I determine if a linked list would be more appropriate than memcpy in terms of efficiency?

From what I've found in the literature and online, benchmarks are considered quite evil.

I'm dealing with around 30 elements (from experience) of small size (3 component vectors : points in space).

What would you use in this case:

1) memcpy + direct access
2) linked list + linear search time

Thanks!

Comment: Benchmarks "considered evil"? What the frak?

Comment: Please show us the "literature" that says that benchmarks are evil.

Comment: Well, the codes that I'm  programming (I'm a Mech. Eng.) deal with numerical simulations in continuum mechanics using the finite volume method. The computations are very complex and they run on HPC clusters. What I meant by "benchmarks are evil" was wrongly put: I meant that there is no sense in benchmarking this thing now, until it's all coded. There are layers and layers to build, and I cannot know at this point, which option is better. I guess I meant "premature optimization", but again, I'm a Mech. Eng., so excuse the wrong terminology...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really care that much about performance, you should measure it, i.e. benchmark your code (this is not evil, it is common practice; *what is evil is premature optimization*).

But be aware that, at least with recent GCC (e.g. GCC 4.6) on GNU/Linux and when optimized by at least -O2, `memcpy` & `memset` are semi-magically (thru `__builtin_memcpy` or similar tricks) transformed to quite efficient code.

And for large set of small data elements, I would guess that caching consideration are dominant w.r.t. performance.

Comment: What exactly does it mean "caching consideration are dominant w.r.t. performance"? I am dealing with a large set of small data elements, and at the end, I will test the different options for the container, as you suggested. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Profiling, or benchmarks, are **not** evil. They are the best way to figure out which of more options is more efficient. With the "smartness" of optmizers nowadays, the counter-intuitive option might actually prove to be the most efficient. I suggest you run a benchmark and choose based on that. The only way you can go wrong is not providing valid input, that covers most cases.

Answer (score 1):

As you a dealing with such a small amount of data - why are you worrying?

Benchmarking only really works with lots of computations - to limit the other effects from the OS.

Answer (score 0):

With a so small dataset ( 30 * 12 bytes ), all your data is inside a cache line. So I4m sure it will be quicker than a list. If you use a list, you still need to allocate a piece of memory, which, on most OS's takes more time than copying such a small piece of memory.